# No autoplay when plugging my mmc sd

Tags: usb, sd-card, autoplay

I'm on Windows 7. When I plug my mmc sd I hear the sound indicating it was identified (and when I unplug I hear the "unplugged" sound). However, the autoplay window doesn't show up. Also, the sd drive doesn't appear on "My Computer". What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling the autoplay feature in control panel. Windows 7 automatically disables autoplay for security reasons.